# Getting TSLint interface error while pushing value into multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, multidimensional-array, interface

I am converting response into Month and Day array and in Day array I have number array. The logic is working fine as expected, But I am getting tslint error near pushing the value into day array,

**Error - Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DayTimeData'.**

Here is the my interface code -

```
export interface SerializeHourValData {
  name: string;
  data: MonthDateTimeData[];
}

export interface MonthDateTimeData {
  [month: number]: DayTimeData[];
}

export interface DayTimeData {
  [day: number]: number[];
}
```

And logical code where I am getting error

```
public valData: SerializeHourValData[] = [];

// Here I am looping through and getting month & day number and from using that I am storing hourlyData in day.

this.valData[index].data[month] = this.valData[index].data[month] || [];
    this.valData[index].data[month][day] = this.valData[index].data[month][day] || [];

    for (const key in hourlyData) {
      if (key.indexOf('h') > -1) {
        this.valData[index].data[month][day].push(+hourlyData[key]); // here i am getting Tslint error for '+hourlyData[key]'
      }
    }
```

[Here is the snapshot how data looks after serialization -](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRbwY.png)

Let me know where i was wrong in interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data models arent matching. When you are trying to push values to the `this.valData[index].data` array it has to be array of `MonthDateTimeData` according to the image that you have shared. But instead you are passing just `number` to the push function of the array.

According to the interface `SerializeHourValData`

```
export interface SerializeHourValData {
  name: string;
  data: MonthDateTimeData[];
}
```

It expects data to be a `MonthDateTimeData` object array. Instead of passing MonthDateTimeData object array you are passing just a number. when pushing a value to the `this.valData[index].data`. Change it according to an array or change your models accordingly. Then it would work fine.

Comment: Thanks, Here it is what i changed

`export interface SerializeHourValData {
  name: string;
  data: MonthDateTimeData[];
}

export type MonthDateTimeData = DayTimeData[];

export type DayTimeData = number[];`

Comment: Happy to help :)